# Clockwise Shifting a Matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

The input is a N x N matrix which has to be shifted cyclically (either Clockwise or Counter-Clockwise) by one element.

**Example Input (Size 3) :**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**Output :**

```
2 3 6
1 5 9
4 7 8
```

**Example Input (Size 4) :**

```
10 20 5  5
22 33 4  10
2  6  8  9
55 11 66 7
```

**Output :**

```
22 10 20 5 
2  6  33 5 
55 8  4  10
11 66 7  9
```

I need to know how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Just give me one minute and I will come back with an algorithm, an implementation and a hot coffee

Comment: @user3476387, I don't think you grasp the magnitude of what you are asking, it's not a matter of "oh, well, apply this three-line function and you'll get it".

Comment: Sorry for asking an implementation. It was a mistake on my part.

Comment: I think the way I would go about it is:
- a function to estimate the number of layers from the raw input
- a function to extract one layer into a linear array, shift in one direction for clockwise, counterclockwise and place it back in the original matrix. Then I'd run through the layers doing this.

Comment: @Jblasco Actually the logic pretty much is a two-liner: `for i, j in product(range(n), range(m)): B[i][j] = A[(i+dx)%n][(j+dy)%m]`

Comment: @NiklasB. Could you maybe explain that code a little bit ?

Comment: @NiklasB., thought about that too, but in the case of 4x4, for example, you want to move 55 up (dy=1, dx=0) while you want to move 22 right (dx=1, dy=0), so you'll need to construct actual matrices dx, dy, right?

Comment: Oh in that case you will have to check which quadrant you're in

Comment: user3476387, did you manage? Let us know if we can help you.

Comment: @Jblasco I have managed to do it & posted it as the answer. Thank You for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For rotation, read elements in the order :**
i -> 0 to n-1 and j = 0
j -> 0 to n-1 and i = n-1
i -> n-1 to 0 and j = n-1
j -> n-1 to 0 and i = 0

```
import collections
def shiftMatrix(matrix, layers, num,rotate_direction):
    for count in range(layers):
        temp1 = []
        i = count
        for j in range(count, num - count):
            temp1.append(matrix[i][j])
        j = num - 1 - count
        for i in range(1 + count, num - count -1):
            temp1.append(matrix[i][j])
        i = num - 1 - count
        for j in range(num - 1 - count, -1 + count, -1):
            temp1.append(matrix[i][j])
        j = count
        for i in range(num - 1 - count - 1, 0 + count, -1):
            temp1.append(matrix[i][j])
        temp = collections.deque(temp1)
        temp.rotate(rotate_direction)
        temp1 = list(temp)
        counter = 0
        i = count
        for j in range(count, num - count):
            matrix[i][j] = temp1[counter]
            counter += 1
        j = num - 1 - count
        for i in range(1 + count, num - count -1):
            matrix[i][j] = temp1[counter]
            counter += 1
        i = num - 1 - count
        for j in range(num - 1 - count, -1 + count, -1):
            matrix[i][j] = temp1[counter]
            counter += 1
        j = count
        for i in range(num - 1 - count - 1, 0 + count, -1):
            matrix[i][j] = temp1[counter]
            counter += 1
        return matrix


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(raw_input())
    op_type = raw_input()
    matrix = []
    for i in range(num):
        temp = []
        input_string = raw_input().split()
        for element in input_string:
            temp.append(int(element))
        matrix.append(temp)
    if(num >= 3):
        layers = num - 3 + 1
    else:
        layers = 1
    if(op_type == "CW"):
        matrix_result = shiftMatrix(matrix,layers,num,1);
    else:
        matrix_result = shiftMatrix(matrix,layers,num,-1);
    print(" ".join((" ".join(map(str,element))) for element in matrix_result))
```

**Explanation :**
The number of layers for a matrix of size N is N-3. For each layer the elements have been collected in a clockwise way & then converted into a queue which is rotated either clockwise or anti-clockwise.